# how to dismiss dialog from OnClick wihout having reference to dialog

Tags: android

I have a class that has a method in which by calling it displays a dialog. This dialog has buttons in which they have listeners.
The problem is that when the onClick is fired, there is no way for me get the dialog so I can dismiss. What should I do in this case? I don't want to store the dialog as a variable because this is static class and don't want to hold a reference to dialog

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.bActionUpgradeSword:
            // do action

            break;
        case R.id.bActionUpgradeArmor:
                // do action        
            break;  
        }

      // I WANT TO DISMISS DIALOG HERE
    }

private void showUpgradeSwordDiag(Activity act){
         Dialog diag = new Dialog(act);
        diag.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        diag.setContentView(R.layout.diag_upgrade_sword_dialog);
        /* add some info to dialog */
        /* set the click listeners */
        diag.show()
}
```

Comment: Might be better to use [DialogBuilder](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)

Comment: This sounds like you do want a reference to a the Dialog, as a field in this containing object.  There's no way to "get all Dialogs and dismiss them now."  :)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

try setting the dialog as tag on view and then get the tag as below

```
 Dialog diag = null;
 Button b = null;
 b.setTag(diag);
 Dialog d = (Dialog) b.getTag();
```

Comment: That may work actually. I will give it a try... Thanks

Comment: You can't call a method on null.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.bActionUpgradeSword:
                // do action
                if(diag!=null){
                diag.dismiss();   
                }
                break;
            case R.id.bActionUpgradeArmor:
                    // do action        
                break;  
            }

          // I WANT TO DISMISS DIALOG HERE
        }
     Dialog diag;
    private void showUpgradeSwordDiag(Activity act){
             diag = new Dialog(act);
            diag.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            diag.setContentView(R.layout.diag_upgrade_sword_dialog);
            /* add some info to dialog */
            /* set the click listeners */
            diag.show()
    }
```

Comment: Thank you but if you see my question, I didnt want to create a variable to hold reference to dialog as the class is static . Idont want the diag reference to be held forever

Answer (score 0):

create a class that implements `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` and override onClick method as you wish. something like this:

```
public void onClick (DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
 switch(which){
  case BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
   dialog.dismiss();
   break;
 }
}
```

Comment: Iam using custom dialog not alert dialog

Comment: pass dialog  to your custom OnClickListener class by constructor